# Set textarea height to height of text

Tags: css, textarea

I want to use a textarea on a form, but I want it to be a single line high when the content is empty (i.e. on a `new` form), and only resize to the height of the content on the `edit` form.

I've been playing around with a few css settings but I'm really not skilled with front-end development, can someone point me in the direction of the attributes I need to be setting to make this happen?

Preferably without JS, but that seems to be the only solution of any I've found thus far. It seems messy and slow when you add in multiple textarea's auto resizing on a single form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this plugin for jQuery: http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize